# How do get "request_id" to use uber sandbox for building url with get method in Android;

Tags: android, authentication, uber-api

I use the following url to get the Uber sandbox response with the post
method & I used three parameter for post method are longitude, lattitude and Access_token.

```
String url = "https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests/{request_id}";
```

I got the above url from uber api for sandbox. Now, how do get above "request_id" to complete URL?

Answer (score 0):

Actually  request_id  is used to get the ride details about driver, Location, vehicle, processing, ETA, and surge multiplier

so to get the request_id  first of all get the authorization code  using authorization url and in this url scope type must be request

next this authorization code is used with in the  10 minute to get the access token and refresh token  ,, add this authorization code in the query parameter of url.

After that this access token is used as authorization bearer code in the header to get the ride details of particular product

with this url https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1/requests in post method and parameters are of ride_request details as given in the UBER api tutorials

then this request gives you a "request_id" also in response,
 you can use it further...